# Problem with using Ext.msg.alert on a popped Panel form

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I'm showing *myFormPanel* includes a form.I'm opening this panel like :

```
popUpPanel = new myFormPanel();
popUpPanel.show();
```

I've put some validations for the form inside that panel and wanted to show such 
validation error message with **Ext.Msg.alert('please enter X');**

Problem is; when I pop this validation message with **Ext.Msg.alert** *myFormPanel* is destroyed.

I think it is because my form and alert uses the same layer so Sencha destroys *myFormPanel* and shows alert message box.

How can I solve this issue? Is it possible to isolate myFormPanel popup layer and **Ext.Msg.alert** layer?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug, but you can simply set `hideOnMaskTap` to `false` overcome this.

Working example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/5DF96/3/) - toggle `hideonMaskTap` to see the effect.

By default, this config is `true`, and in documentation,

> True to automatically bind a tap listener to the mask that hides the window. Defaults to true. Note: if you set this property to false you have to programmaticaly hide the overlay.

It seems like `Msg.alert` is causing some confusion here and `FormPanel` think you are clicking on the mask, and hence causes the panel to dismiss. Perhaps this is the quickest way to solve your problem for now.